# Can qnamaker.ai load a url not open for the public?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I'm setting up a QnA bot in Teams for internal use. However our FAQ page is whitelisted by IP and only accessible from the company office. I’ve tried whitelisting all known Azure service IP-addresses to no avail.

Is it possible to grant qnamaker.ai access to the private URL? If so what IP-address should be whitelisted? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QnA Maker Management Service uses the following IP Ranges:

- West US: `13.91.0.0/16`
- East US: `52.191.0.0/18`

qnamaker.ai uses a few others, depending on where you're accessing it from. If whitelisting the above IP ranges doesn't work, let me know what region you're trying to access it from and I can provide additional guidance.

Comment: This solved my problem. Think it has to do that the cognitive service is active in West US. However I'm running the service from West Europe. Incase the cognitive service is available in West Europe, what range should I use then?

Comment: @Kage The site scraping service only runs from West/East US, so you'd use the same IP range.